# Implement Google Maps client side

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a rails app where the admins are creating information about shops (name, description, address, directions etc). I want the admins to create a map for the shop as well, and I have understood that implementing this client-side (both for admins and users) is the way to go as I will hit the daily cap (2500 requests/day) that Google Maps has.

How would a map-creating implementation for the admins look like? Most of the times there will be addresses at hand, but sometimes not so something like a manual procedure (click on the map) has to work as well.

Comment: It wil be the same for both .. check answer below .. did i understand correctly ?

Comment: Do you have any example code what the implementation could look like?

Comment: I have updated my answer below .. feel free to accept it if it helps you.

Comment: I see you have accepted .. you can upvote it too if it was helpful @yor mazar. Thanks anyways .. cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be the same for admin as well as others (by that I mean it will be in the browser, ofcourse you can serve out different maps depending on your needs) . [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) is a client side solution.

Incase you need to encode addresses on the Map have a look at the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) .

Examples [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) might be of use.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I have added the examples link too.